# Appearance of sentence parameters in a theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is it true that if $A$ is a formula in a Hilbert system $H$, then if $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ is a proof of $A$ in $H$, any sentence parameter not appearing in $A$ doesn't appear in $B_1,\ldots,B_n$? If it's true, how to show it?

Comment: I think I should reformulate my question. Is it true that if $A$ is a formula in a Hilbert system $H$, then if $A$ is provable, it is always possible to find a proof $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ of $A$ in which all the sentence parameters being there are sentence parameters of $A$? If it's true, how to show it?

Comment: Are you asking whether all the subformulae of intermediate conclusions in a proof of A must also be subformulae of A?  In general, the answer is no.  As to _whether_ such a proof can be found, the answer for many reasonable systems:  the answer is yes, you can find a proof that doesn't involve unnecessary formula or derivations.   These kinds of results may be related to  [cut-elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem) (which holds for many systems).  Smullyan calls such proofs analytic.  The property of these proofs he calls the "subformula principle."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What counts as a Hilbert system?

Do you mean a theory whose deductive apparatus is Hilbertian? Well, suppose $T$ is a theory with a classical Hilbertian deductive system, and the non-logical axiom  $P \land Q$. Then $T$ will prove $Q$. But  $Q$ isn't provable from the logic alone, so any proof of $Q$ will have to involve the premiss $P \land Q$. So there is a propositional letter earlier in proof which isn't in the conclusion.

Or do you mean a pure Hilbertian system of logic? Well note that a propositional logic with particular sentences as axioms (rather than with axiom schemata) and a substitution rule  and modus ponens as the sole rules of inference would often (usually?) be counted as Hilbertian. And obviously in such systems where e.g. $P \to P$ is an axiom and $(Q \land R) \to (Q \land R)$ is derived in one step by substitution, then again there is a propositional letter earlier in proof which isn't in the conclusion.